# @attributes index missing in xml object on one server while with same input it is present on other server PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a response coming from an API then I am using below line of code for its conversion to an XML object

```
$response = sendRemoteRequest($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

What my issue is that for the same $url and the same $response I am getting different results in `$xml`.
Please see below the result
Expected (which is already happening on one server) :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ack] => Success
    [version] => 1.13.0
    [timestamp] => 2020-05-18T10:44:43.266Z
    [searchResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 10
                )

            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 233561233897
                            [title] => 100PC DISPOSABLE SAFETY GLOVES POWDER FREE LATEX FREE TATTOO MECHANIC VALETING
                            [globalId] => EBAY-GB
                            [primaryCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [categoryId] => 31474
                                    [categoryName] => Disposable Gloves
                                )

                            [secondaryCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [categoryId] => 177095
                                    [categoryName] => Gloves
                                )

                            [galleryURL] => https://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/pict/2335612338974040_1.jpg
                            [viewItemURL] => https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/710-53481-19255-0/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5338651929&customid=&lgeo=1&vectorid=229508&item=233561233897
                            [paymentMethod] => PayPal
                            [autoPay] => true
                            [postalCode] => B714JH
                            [location] => West Bromwich,United Kingdom
                            [country] => GB
                            [shippingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [shippingServiceCost] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [currencyId] => GBP
                                                )

                                            [0] => 0.0
                                        )

                                    [shippingType] => Free
                                    [shipToLocations] => Worldwide
                                )

                            [sellingStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [currentPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [currencyId] => GBP
                                                )

                                            [0] => 14.95
                                        )

                                    [convertedCurrentPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [currencyId] => GBP
                                                )

                                            [0] => 14.95
                                        )

                                    [sellingState] => Active
                                    [timeLeft] => P29DT0H33M43S
                                )

                            [listingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [bestOfferEnabled] => false
                                    [buyItNowAvailable] => false
                                    [startTime] => 2020-04-16T11:18:26.000Z
                                    [endTime] => 2020-06-16T11:18:26.000Z
                                    [listingType] => StoreInventory
                                    [gift] => false
                                    [watchCount] => 206
                                )

                            [condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [conditionId] => 1000
                                    [conditionDisplayName] => New
                                )

                            [isMultiVariationListing] => true
                            [topRatedListing] => true
                        )
)
```

You can see `@attributes` under `sellingStatus`. This is what I want in below response also (which is NOT happening on other server

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ack] => Success
    [version] => 1.13.0
    [timestamp] => 2020-05-18T10:44:40.799Z
    [searchResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 10
                )

            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 233561233897
                            [title] => 100PC DISPOSABLE SAFETY GLOVES POWDER FREE LATEX FREE TATTOO MECHANIC VALETING
                            [globalId] => EBAY-GB
                            [primaryCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [categoryId] => 31474
                                    [categoryName] => Disposable Gloves
                                )

                            [secondaryCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [categoryId] => 177095
                                    [categoryName] => Gloves
                                )

                            [galleryURL] => https://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/pict/2335612338974040_1.jpg
                            [viewItemURL] => https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/710-53481-19255-0/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5338651929&customid=&lgeo=1&vectorid=229508&item=233561233897
                            [paymentMethod] => PayPal
                            [autoPay] => true
                            [postalCode] => B714JH
                            [location] => West Bromwich,United Kingdom
                            [country] => GB
                            [shippingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [shippingServiceCost] => 0.0
                                    [shippingType] => Free
                                    [shipToLocations] => Worldwide
                                )

                            [sellingStatus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [currentPrice] => 14.95
                                    [convertedCurrentPrice] => 14.95
                                    [sellingState] => Active
                                    [timeLeft] => P29DT0H33M46S
                                )

                            [listingInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [bestOfferEnabled] => false
                                    [buyItNowAvailable] => false
                                    [startTime] => 2020-04-16T11:18:26.000Z
                                    [endTime] => 2020-06-16T11:18:26.000Z
                                    [listingType] => StoreInventory
                                    [gift] => false
                                    [watchCount] => 206
                                )

                            [condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [conditionId] => 1000
                                    [conditionDisplayName] => New
                                )

                            [isMultiVariationListing] => true
                            [topRatedListing] => true
                        )
```

There is no `@attributes` in `sellingstatus`. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Don't rely on using the output of things like `print_r()` for SimpleXML, use `->asXML()` (or just the XML before loading it) to check the contents.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked for any differences between these servers (PHP version, configuration, using different endpoints,....)?

Comment: Hey, friend Kindly tell me why it is different in both? I have read about print_r and many other things of accessing '@attributes' but my question is that why this '@attribute' is missing?

Comment: @NicoHaase Haase You have a good point about difference between servers. I am aware of the version that both are same (7.1.33) I have phpinof() with me but its long content so can not paste here. Can you tell me some config points to check with both server?

Comment: The important question is: can you access that attribute? If the only difference is in the `print_r` output, you can just shrug and get on with your day; if you have actual useful code that runs on one server but not the other, post a [mcve] showing us that, and we might be able to help.

Comment: @IMSoP its a huge code sorry I can not reproduce it for example. Just in short consider that I want this result
`$var = ['sellingStatus']['currentPrice'][0];`
so `$var` should be `14.95` in both cases.
Currently it is correct for the first pasted response but NOT Correct for the second response as there this indexes (`['sellingStatus']['currentPrice'][0`]) does not satisfy

Comment: @ChanchalS It may sound like we're making work for you by asking you to break the problem down into smaller pieces, but trust me, that is one of the most important skills to learn as a developer. Create a new file; paste in the XML (not the `print_r` result!); add some PHP to access the element you're having trouble with; check you can reproduce the error; delete parts of the XML to make the example smaller; keep going until you can't delete anything else and still reproduce the error. By then, either you'll have solved the problem yourself, or you'll have a much better question to ask us.